# Selected Exercise for Linear Algebra Done Right Edition 3

Tags: self-learning, homework, linear-algebra

I am self learning the book *Linear Algebra Done Right*. I tried to complete all exercises in each chapter. I am currently at Chapter 3 and found that it is not feasible to complete all of the exercises. (I want to finish the book this year and I started in January.)

Actually, I don't know whether I should complete all of the exercises. Many of the text's questions are difficult for me. Most of the time, I have try a few times. So, I cannot decide whether to skip a question or not. If I can know the approach to the question by just looking at it, I can decide to skip. But often this is not the case.

So, I am wondering, if anyone has taken a course that use the book (3rd edition), and can list some problems for each chapter (maybe from problem sets)?

Comment: I disagree with the closure of this question. It is addressed to math educators, by a student attempting to self-study, and seeking math educators' input wrt what is reasonably expected in terms of assigned exercises.  Hence it belongs here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Syllabus for linear algebra using Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&ei=21XAXOrwM8K4tQWCgpzgAw&q=syllabus+for+linear+algebra+using+Linear+Algebra+Done+Right&oq=syllabus+for+linear+algebra+using+Linear+Algebra+Done+Right&gs_l=psy-ab.12...15311.25049..27150...0.0..2.643.3906.0j19j1j5-2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i10.LOC2eJsjkjs) for current/past courses being taught with the text as the primary text in a linear algebra class.

In particular, see [MIT's Open Courseware (OCW) model for Linear Algebra using Axler's text](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-700-linear-algebra-fall-2013/syllabus/).  You can download the course materials for the MIT course, to supplement your study of the text [here, including assigned problem sets](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-700-linear-algebra-fall-2013/download-course-materials/).

Also see the [on-line syllabus from Berkeley for "Linear Algebra"](https://math.berkeley.edu/~ogus/Math_110--008/index.html) using the text.  On the linked course outline, you'll find links to homework assignments, supplementary study material, and some solutions to assigned homework.

Good luck!

Comment: Found an updated class that uses Edition 3: https://math.berkeley.edu/~ribet/110/

Answer (score 0):

One book I read over the last few years, in the preface, mentions that some problem sets contain problems logically covered in a later chapter. The author says these problems were set as challenges requiring a little creative insight, beyond the explicit content of the current chapter but within the scope of the book. I think it was this book.

Comment: Is your suggestion that someone self-learning using this textbook should do the challenge problems? Did you do them? Have you assigned them to others? Right now this doesn't really feel like an answer to the question.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisCunningham. This should be a comment on OP, not an answer.